# Remove blank line from else statement

Tags: php

I've been researching if/else statements, and I've built one without any issue, on my else statement I use `$tpl->set('message', '');` the '' quotes are to indicate to not show anything (which is what I want), on my template I use {message} to echo a message during the if statement, but I was wondering, as I don't want to echo anything on an else statement is leaving the quotes empty best practice?, as with it empty it keeps the {message} hidden on my template which is what I wanted, sorry if my question is rather basic, I'm still learning, thank you very much.

Edit: Just to clarify with the title, on the html output where the {message} would appear is a blank line, is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can just check if the `message` is empty or not using the `empty()`. If the $message is not empty, only then show the message as below.

```
 <?php if(!empty($message): ?>
   {$message}
 <?php endif ?>
```

Note: I don't know what templating you are using. So, this is the basic idea, you might need some adjustment to fit it for the template you are using.